# SurfaceView keeps overdrawing the menu

Tags: android

When I create a SurfaceView and then try to open the menu, the menu is stuck under the SurfaceView.
When I set the surfaceView to be transparant, this works when the SurfaceView is empty, but once it's filled, it will not allow anything to be in front of it.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
This is my init:

```
    private void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    holder.addCallback(this);
```

[image: SurfaceView over the menu]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the possibility to force the android menu to be overdrawn a surface. What I did some time ago having an GLSurface is to implement my own menu and add it to the view list after the surface. Here is an example (could not compile):

```
   surface = new GLSurfaceView(this, handler);
   menu = new MenuView(context);

   menu.setOption("Option 1");
   menu.setOption("Option 2");

   surface.setRenderer(new OpenGLRenderer(handler));
   setContentView(surface);

   addContentView(menu, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: This menu isn't generated by myself, this is an automated menu generated by the system. Thus i think i have to do something with the SurfaceView it self e.g. the way it updates it self.

Comment: I had the same problem with the system menu so I did my own :D

Comment: I now rooted the android and removed the whole menu bar in my application, this works sufficient.